# Extra blank lines in email saved in activities

Tags: email, activities

When an email is sent with the non-bulk method, the copy of the email saved in the activity has extra blank lines at each paragraph end. Whilst not a big issue, it makes reading less easy because you have to scroll more and if you want to re-use the text you have to delete them all. With the bulk mail there is no problem. Is it something in my set up, a bug or a feature?

I'm on CiviCRM 5.26.2 and WordPress 5.6.1 but I think its a general thing and certainly not new.

Comment: It's come up before and there were lines added for a reason, but which borks other things - will see if I can find.

Comment: Ok I was thinking of something similar but different: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/31574/181. There the problem was "Memo/Richtext" vs "TextArea" will display newlines differently. For this issue here though if the email was plaintext instead of html, the newlines might be needed.